# How can i add my program to the right click context menu and pass it's path

Tags: python-3.x, file, windows-10, contextmenu, right-click

I'm looking for a way to add my program to the right-click context menu and when I click my program from there it will receive the path of the file

we can use this code as the program that would run when I click it from the context menu for example:
`print('chosen file:', path)`

I would appreciate a step-by-step explanation...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at this It looks like it explains your question properly. If you still have questions feel free to comment

https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/ghp716/add_python_script_to_rightclick_menu_context_menu/

Comment: Yeah ive watched it i still dont really understand how it works.. do you mind giving me a more detailed example?